# Need direction about Binary Search Tree implementation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures

I have a partial implementation of a binary tree that doesn't work properly. I believe I am missing fundamental knowledge about struct memory management in objective-c but not sure what it is(besides malloc). When I try to create a new tree node based on a struct I get

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

which led me to believe I didn't create a memory location for this struct pointer. What is the proper way of doing this in Objective-C? (Code in below)

Thank you for taking the time to respond. The code seems correct from the logic perspective so not sure what the issue is here.

**EDIT**
I've modified the source code based on @trungduc 's response. But now I am getting a stack overflow in the printDescription method 
issue:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3fffe8) // on line [self printDescription:root.left];
```

PS. 
I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066057/binary-tree-in-objective-c/) but didn't help. I also saw [this repo](https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKAlgorithms) but I am not sure happy with some of the implementation details so I ended up not following it. Does anyone know any good guides/tutorials on how to do trees and graphs in Objective-C?

**Main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// BSTNode is an Objective-C class
@interface BSTNode : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int data;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BSTNode *left;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BSTNode *right;

@end

@implementation BSTNode

@end

@interface BST: NSObject

- (BSTNode *)insertNode:(BSTNode *)root withData:(int)data;
- (void)printDescription:(BSTNode *)root;

@end

@implementation BST

- (BSTNode *)initializeTreeNode {
    // By default, |data| is 0, |left| is nil, |right| is nil
    return [[BSTNode alloc] init];
}

- (BSTNode *)insertNode:(BSTNode *)root withData:(int)data {
    if(!root) {
        root = [self initializeTreeNode];
        root.data = data;
    } else if (root.data >= data) {
        root.left = [self insertNode:root.left withData:data];
    } else {
        root.right = [self insertNode:root.right withData:data];
    }

    return root;
}

- (void)printDescription:(BSTNode *)root {
    // in order left - root - right
    [self printDescription:root.left];
    NSLog(@"%d",root.data);
    [self printDescription:root.right];
}

@end
```

and inside the main method:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        BST *bst = [[BST alloc] init];;
        BSTNode *root = [[BSTNode alloc]init];
        [bst insertNode:root withData:20];
        [bst insertNode:root withData:15];
        [bst insertNode:root withData:25];
        [bst printDescription:root];
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a struct. Use a class; it is *Objective*-C after all

Comment: malloc(sizeof(BSTNode)) for a new node

Comment: Thanks for the response, although your answer specifically solves my memory issue. I ended up going with the more Object oriented approach in below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got crash because you called `node->data` while `node` is `NULL`.

In this case, I suggest to define `BSTNode` as an Objective-C class. You can try my code below.

```
// BSTNode is an Objective-C class
@interface BSTNode : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int data;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BSTNode *left;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BSTNode *right;

@end

@implementation BSTNode

@end

@interface BST: NSObject

- (BSTNode *)insertNode:(BSTNode *)root withData:(int)data;
- (void)printDescription:(BSTNode *)root;

@end

@implementation BST

- (BSTNode *)initializeTreeNode {
  // By default, |data| is 0, |left| is nil, |right| is nil
  return [[BSTNode alloc] init];
}

- (BSTNode *)insertNode:(BSTNode *)root withData:(int)data {
  if(!root) {
    root = [self initializeTreeNode];
    root.data = data;
  } else if (root.data >= data) {
    root.left = [self insertNode:root.left withData:data];
  } else {
    root.right = [self insertNode:root.right withData:data];
  }

  return root;
}

- (void)printDescription:(BSTNode *)root {
  if (!root) {
      return;
  }

  // in order left - root - right
  [self printDescription:root.left];
  NSLog(@"%d",root.data);
  [self printDescription:root.right];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Although your answer is clean and easy to understand I am getting a stack overflow in the print description `[self printDescription:root.left];` any idea why would that be? I updated the question.

Comment: @Matt I have updated `printDescription`, you can check and try again.

Comment: @Matt Take a look at https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKAlgorithms/tree/master/EKAlgorithms/Data%20Structures if you need a good sample

Comment: I was actually following that. Although it was useful for the most part, I didn't like how he used `NSComparisonResult` `selector` on insert and find methods for the BST. Do you have any alternative suggestions for BST and Graph examples?

Comment: I checked but I didn't find anything related to `NSComparisonResult` in `EKBTree.m` file

Comment: checkout `EKBSTree.m` the `EKBTree.m` implementation was fine.